# Refraction equation, quartic equation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polynomials, numerical-methods, euclidean-geometry

Given two points $P$ and $Q$, a line ($A$, $B$ - orthogonal projection of $P$, $Q$ onto the line) and a coefficient $n$, I want to find out such point $C$ that $\frac{\sin{a}}{\sin{b}}=n$ (in fact, it's an equation of light refraction). I also assume that $C$ lies between $A$ and $B$. See the image below:

[image]

**What I know is: $w, h, d, n$. What I want to calculate is $x$.**

I need to find the easiest solution possible, in order to calculate $x$ in a computer's application very efficiently.

What I've found out so far is:

$$n=\frac{\sin{a}}{\sin{b}}=\frac{\frac{d-x}{\sqrt{(d-x)^2+w^2}}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}}=\frac{(d-x)\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}{x\sqrt{(d-x)^2+w^2}}$$

Hence, we need to solve this equation for $x$ (assuming $0<x<d$):

$n^2x^2((d-x)^2+w^2)=(d-x)^2(x^2+h^2)$

which yields:

$f(x)=(n^2-1)x^4-2d(n^2-1)x^3+((d^2+w^2)(n^2-1)+w^2-h^2)x^2+2dh^2x-d^2h^2 = 0$

That way we obtained a quartic equation. How to solve it? I've tried using the Ferrari's solution, but the result is very complicated. Moreover, this equation can have as many as four real roots but I know it's got only one root for $0<x<d$. Do you have any idea how to simplify this equation or maybe you can suggest me an easier way to find $x$?

Comment: Since the solution for n=1 appears to be simple, perhaps you could let $(n^2-1)=\epsilon$ and use [singular perturbations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory#Example_of_second-order_singular_perturbation_theory) to get an asymptotic form of the solution

Comment: @Valentin: I need a solution for $n>1$ (or at least for $n=1.33$). I'd prefer to find an exact solution.

Comment: asymptotc expansion will give you a solution valid for some range of $n>1$ which should be computationally more efficient than horror like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n2−1%29x4−2d%28n2−1%29x3%2B%28%28d2%2Bw%5E2%29%28n2−1%29%2Bw%5E2−p2%29x2%2B2d*h%5E2x−%28d%5E2%29*h%5E2%3D0). what is p?

Comment: $p$ was supposed to be $h$; I fixed it.

Comment: @joriki: Right, thanks for fixing it ;)

Comment: Have you heard of Snell's Law?

Comment: Yes, but deriving $x$ from Snell's Law gives the same result - quartic equation. In fact, my problem is to find the point of refraction of light according to Snell's Law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using a numerical method, you might as well stick with a non-polynomial form of your equation that is more well-behaved. In particular, you could just solve
$$\frac{(d-x)/\sqrt{(d-x)^2+w^2}}{x/\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}=n$$
for $x$. The left-hand side is a monotonically decreasing function of $x$ between $0$ and $d$, because the numerator is nonnegative and decreasing and the denominator is nonnegative and increasing. So you can just apply bisection search and it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: For example, [here's the graph for your example in the comments](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%28d-x%29/sqrt%28%28d-x%29%5E2%2bw%5E2%29%29/%28x/sqrt%28x%5E2%2bh%5E2%29%29%20-%201.33%20where%20w=1,%20h=5,%20d=30%20for%20x=0..30). I brought $n$ to the other side of the equation so you can see the solution as the zero crossing.

Comment: Right, converting the original equation into a polynomial introduces unwanted ambiguity. The polynomial can have as many as four roots while there's only one correct solution to the original problem. I just hoped that I could find a descent analytic solution but it turns out that a numerical method is the only way to solve the problem efficiently.

Comment: I've tested it and it works great! Only 10-20 iterations of bisection search is enough. I could also improve the solution using Newton's method.

Answer (score 2):

[A plot of a typical example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28n%5E2-1%29%20x%5E4%20-%202%20d%20%28n%5E2%20-%201%29%20x%5E3%20%2b%20%28%28d%5E2%2bw%5E2%29%28n%5E2%20-%201%29%20%2b%20w%5E2%20-%20h%5E2%29%20x%5E2%2b2%20d%20h%5E2%20x%20-%20d%5E2h%5E2%20where%20n=1.33,w=1,h=1,d=1) shows that the right-hand side of your last displayed equation behaves rather nicely and it should be possible to obtain the solution efficiently using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which wouldn't require drawing any roots and should yield the result to sufficient accuracy within a few iterations that only involve a couple of multiplications and additions and one division each.

You could use the solution $x=dh/(h+w)$ for $n=1$ as the initial value for the iteration.

By the way, I'd divide through by $d^4$ to get rid of the irrelevant scale and express everything relative to $d$:

$$\epsilon\xi^4-2\epsilon\xi^3+((1+\omega^2)\epsilon+\omega^2-\eta^2)\xi^2+2\eta^2\xi-\eta^2=0\;,$$

with $\epsilon=n^2-1$, $\xi=x/d$, $\omega=w/d$ and $\eta=h/d$ with initial value $\xi_0=\eta/(\eta+\omega)$.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this method if it's accurate enough.

Comment: Although it generally works well for $x=dh/(h+w)$, there is a problem for [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28n%5E2-1%29+x%5E4+-+2+d+%28n%5E2+-+1%29+x%5E3+%2B+%28%28d%5E2%2Bw%5E2%29%28n%5E2+-+1%29+%2B+w%5E2+-+h%5E2%29+x%5E2%2B2+d+h%5E2+x+-+d%5E2h%5E2+where+n%3D1.33%2Cw%3D1%2C+h%3D5%2Cd%3D30). Starting with $x=25$ the result is getting close to $x=30$ while $x=30$ is not a root. The correct result can be obtained starting with $x=0$ which gives approx. $5.7$. Also I'm not sure if starting with $x=0$ always gives the correct result.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: when starting with $x=0$, it converges to $-5.7$ (which means $n=-1.33$). The correct result can be obtained starting for example with $x=1$ or $x=12.5$. Do you have any idea how to choose the starting point which guarantees the convergence and the correct result?

Comment: @miloszmaki: No, sorry, I wasn't expecting such difficult behaviour in other cases from the example I tried. You could use more robust methods like [regula falsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi) instead (starting with $x\in[0,d]$), or use such a method to get close and then switch to Newton's method to improve convergence.

Comment: That's a good idea. Finding a root for $0<x<d$ is guaranteed, since $f(0)=-d^2h^2<0$ and $f(d)=d^2n^2w^2>0$ and $f$ is continous.