# Optimize ray path going through an axis aligned box

Tags: optimization

I'm confronted with a problem in which I must minimize a travel path going from some transmitter $T$ to a receiver $R$, going through an interface -- i.e. a change in velocity causing refraction -- and having to pass through a point P of an axis aligned box.

In certain situation, the point $P$ must be reached after a reflection occurred on an interface located behind the axis aligned box. In diagrams, the kind of situation I'm confronted with can be represented as follow:

[image: Letters defines "leg segment" of the path. Green box various velocities associated with these segment.]

Note that, after having reached point P, P starts to act as a point source for the ray going from P to R. That is, the path from P-->I_R-->R is independent from the path from T-->I_T-->C-->P. Note further that to each segment in the path correspond a particular velocity.

The problem can thus be formulated as:

1. Given $T$ and $R$, find $P$ in the axis aligned box such that $f^T_R(P)$ is minized where:

$$f^T_R(P) = d(T, I_T(P))\frac{1}{v_1} + d(I_T(P), C)\frac{1}{v_2} + d(C(P),P)\frac{1}{v_3} + d(P,I_R(P))\frac{1}{v_4} + d(I_R(P),R)\frac{1}{v_1}$$

where $d(x,y)$ is the euclidian distance in 2D and where $I_T(P), I_R(P)$ give the interface point for a given $P$. These last two function are defined implicitly by the quartic equation derive in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150769/refraction-equation-quartic-equation).

**I'm wondering what method I could use to guarantee that I converge (or compute) the global minimum of this problem.** I already know that, under some situation, the minimum $P$ need not be unisuqe. In particular, we can posit $v_2 = v_3 = v_4$ and $T = R$. Then, placing the axis aligned box directly to the right of $T$, any point perpendicular to the interface going to $C$ would minimize $f^T_T$.

[image]

**tl;dr**: What method should I use to guarantee that I converge to the global minimum value of this function? It's unclear to me that the problem is convex and while the global minimum must exist I'm afraid I may either diverge or converge to the wrong point.

**N.B.** My initial hope had been to show that the function was convex by showing that various terms of the sum were, but the path from $T$ to $C$ is not. To show this, pose $T = (-1,0)$, $C = (k,y(\theta))$ and $\theta$ the angle of incidence of the ray going from $T$ to the interface. Then $$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{\cos{\theta}} + \frac{k}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{\sin{\theta}}{n})^2}}$$

where $n = \frac{v_1}{v_2}$ is travel time from $T$ to $C$. This function is not convex for $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ given large enough values of $k$.

[image]

Comment: Why is the light not bent by entering your box, even though it is bent by leaving (first diagram)?

Comment: Once the path from T to P is "completed", the path from P to R is independent from it. In other words, the path can always be split "around" P in such a way that T to P and R to P are independent from one another. In my diagram, had I changed the T for another point T', the path from P to R would have stayed the same. This is because I'm not really dealing with a light ray but rather with a sound wave, of which I'm taking the shortest ray following the wavefront.